# Tag [appstore-sandbox] used for itunesconnect test-users

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I found several posts that use [appstore-sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstore-sandbox) for questions with the so called ["Sandbox Enviroment" of iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html). This sandbox is typically used for testing In-App Purchases but also for game-center testing. But the tag appstore-sandbox is defined for OS X Applications that use the sandbox of App sold through Mac App Store.

The [sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sandbox) is [not even appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sandbox/info) for test-environment but purely for protecting code.

Would it be helpful to have a tag called [itunesconnect-sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect-sandbox)? or rename the appstore-sandbox to something more OSX like [osx-sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-sandbox)?

Comment: I just made the adjustment for those I found, removing appstore-sandbox and adding tags like testing, in-app-purchase, storekit, gamecenter or whatever appropriate. See activity in my SO-profile.